# how to replace square brackets from a string in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I have a string from which I get just the number with 6 charactes using `findAll()` but tha returns me the number in this format `[111111]` I want to get rid of the square brackets and save it to a variable. I have tried this but it does not remove the brackers:

```
def msg = "Fix for bug 861768 and 3v3 player number 24"
def bugNumber = msg.findAll( /\d{6}/ ).toString()
bugNumber.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
println bugNumber
```

This is the output I get:
`[861768]`

No need to say I just started with groovy so probably the code has some mistakes. But any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msg.findAll( /\d{6}/ )` returns an array of strings found.

if you want just first element found then use `msg.findAll( /\d{6}/ ) [0]`

or `msg.find( /\d{6}/ )`

if you want all of them delimited with coma `msg.findAll( /\d{6}/ ).join(',')`

Comment: thanks, I was using findAll when what I really needed was find...

Comment: but it doesnt answer the question. its only a workaround!!!! :(
I have the same question!

Comment: why it's workaround? what's wrong with the answer? maybe you have another question? ;)